# How to add value to array without oerwritting and access those values

Tags: laravel, session, cart

Hello I'm trying to add products to a cart without overwritting the previous product added to the cart and without duplicating if the two products are the same but instead increment the quantity by 1.

Here's how i'm setting up my cart and adding products to it:

```
public function addToCart(Request $request)
    {
        $id = $request->product_id;
        $product = Product::find($id);
        $request->session()->put('cart', [
            [
                "id" => $product->id,
                "name" => $product->name,
                "price" => $product->price,
                "image" => $product->image,
                "quantity" => 1,],
        ]);
        $cart = $request->session()->only(['cart']);
        dd($cart);
        return redirect('cart');
    }
```

And this is what i get from the `dd`

```
array:1 [▼
  "cart" => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:5 [▼
      "id" => 1
      "name" => "name"
      "price" => 42.42
      "image" => "../image.jpg"
      "quantity" => 1
    ]
  ]
]
```

I tried using `put` or `cart[] = [product infos...]` instead of `push` but it would still overwrite the previous product

Also I'm confused as to how to access each product stored in my cart individually, i can access to the whole cart via `$request->session()->only(['cart'])` but i can't find how to access the products of that cart.

Answer (score 1):

Well the problem is in here:

```
 $request->session()->put('cart', [
            [
                "id" => $product->id,
                "name" => $product->name,
                "price" => $product->price,
                "image" => $product->image,
                "quantity" => 1,],
        ]);
```

You create two arrays. So either change this part to:

```
 $request->session()->put('cart', [
            "id" => $product->id,
            "name" => $product->name,
            "price" => $product->price,
            "image" => $product->image,
            "quantity" => 1,
        ]);
```

or this part:

```
cart[] = [product infos...]
```

to

```
cart[0][] = [product infos...]
```

but not both.

Also, a better and more used practice is not to store the whole cart in session, but to store it in tables **carts** and **cart_items** and to store in session only a hash.

Comment: Oh i see, thank you ! I'll try creating new tables to store my cart. But then I'm not sure what my order table should look like.

Comment: well usually you would have carts that have cart_items (cart_id), the orders have order_items (order_id) and then you have M:N relation betweem cart_items and order_items like for example cart_item_order_item table that has data like quantity, price

Comment: Okay, thanks for all the advices and help.